# What is the exact meaning of 'N' bit processor ? , clarification for freescale arch

Tags: cpu-architecture

While reading one Freescale processor manual I stuck somewhere, which specifies that it is a *32-bit processor*.

May I know the exact meaning and logic behind that?

## Update:

Does it specify its ALU width or its address width or its register width specifically or all of them together is N-bit each.

## Update:

Hope you have heard of Freescale processors. I just came across their site which describes one of their latest Starcore-based processor known as SC3850 as a 16-bit processor. As far as I know, it has 32 bit program counters, including ALU, and 40-bit register width and 2x64 bit address bus width. Also the SC3850 can handle SIMD(2) instructions which are of 32 bit or 64 bit.

For more details please go through [this link](http://forums.freescale.com/t5/StarCore-DSPs/Why-SC3850-is-classified-under-16-bit-category-or-quot-meaning/td-p/67869)

Comment: if you search Google for your question topic, you can quickly find answer.

Comment: Too late to give the correct answer but for future references, an `n-bit CPU` means that **its ALU operates on n-bit data words** (usually per clock cycle). Some CPUs have larger data registers (Saturn), or larger (80286)/smaller (i386SX) address registers. For example, the Saturn used in several HP calculators processes nibbles, it's a 4-bit CPU with 64-bit data registers and 20-bit address registers. Its ALU chains the nibble operations to operate on larger words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major reasons you would care about the register width of the processor is performance. Generally doubling the number of bits doubles the rate at which a processor can move data around, and compute.  This is why we're not all using 8 bit processors.

The other major reason is address space. A 16 bit program counter limits you to 64k of address space, and a 32 bit counter limits you to 4 gigabytes. The new 64 bit processors make it possible, if all the address lines are present, to support 17,179,869,184 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: But why we are using in the multiple of 8 for address and data bus widths?

Comment: because the primary measure unit is the bit and the next great order measure unit is byte (8bit) so it's mathematically convenient to work with multiple of 8 bit!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i dont have a definitive answer but i would guess that 8 being a power of 2, is an important factor. Being a power of 2 also means that certain optimisations may be performed by dividing the 8 bits into groups which also means lookup tables can be used for certain operations. 8 bits in the past was also the perfect size when dealing wiht plain old ascii characters. I can imagine that using 5 bit bytes and encoding a string of ascii characters across memory would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the Wikipedia entry on [32-bit processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit), from the entry:

> In computer architecture, 32-bit
>   integers, memory addresses, or other
>   data units are those that are at most
>   32 bits (4 octets) wide. Also, 32-bit
>   CPU and ALU architectures are those
>   that are based on registers, address
>   buses, or data buses of that size.
>   32-bit is also a term given to a
>   generation of computers in which
>   32-bit processors were the norm.

Read and understand the article - then the answer for `N` will be obvious.